# Как сделать чтобы фотографии позиционировались только по ширине

Tags: android

Перерыла кучу литературы и не смогла найти...
Как сделать чтобы фотографии позиционировались только по ширине. У меня есть несколько фоток и я хотела бы чтоб они размещались на странице по верхнему размеру, по горизонтали. Масштабировались чтобы занимать все пространство телефона.

Фотки должны умещаться на одной странице в формате LinearLayout.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: нашла... Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что вы хотите растянуть изображение на весь экран. Для этого нужно будет привязать `ImageView` к краям экрана, указав ширину и высоту **0dp**. Используйте `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:src="@drawable/photo" />
```

Или со свойством `layout_constraintDimensionRatio`, чтобы сохранить пропорцию, например, **1:1**.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:src="@drawable/photo" />
```

[image: Изображине синий квадрат]

Comment: Я не указала. Фотки должны умещаться на одной странице в формате <LinearLayout>...

Answer (score 0):

Все, нашла...

android:scaleType="fitXY"

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Спасибо!